# Notiication when user selects entry from notification center

Tags: ios5, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

When a user selects an entry from the push notification center, it triggers the

```
 application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:
```

method on the application delegate. Is there a way to tell when a push notification is triggered while the user is in the app, and when they select an older push from their notification center?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to tell when a push notification is triggered while the user is in the app[...]?

For this I always understood that

```
application:didReceiveRemoteNotification
```

is called for every notification received after you start up the app, even if it is on foreground. Although I haven't had the need to do this (and can't confirm it at the moment), so I am calling on theory only. But that's what I can understand from the following on [Local and Push Notification Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/IPhoneOSClientImp/IPhoneOSClientImp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH103-SW4).

> iOS Note: In iOS, you can determine whether an application is launched as a result of the user tapping the action button or whether the notification was delivered to the already-running application by examining the application state. In the delegate’s implementation of the application:didReceiveRemoteNotification: or application:didReceiveLocalNotification: method, get the value of the applicationState property and evaluate it. If the value is UIApplicationStateInactive, the user tapped the action button; if the value is UIApplicationStateActive, **the application was frontmost when it received the notification**.

has for

> Is there a way to tell when [...](a user) select an older push from their notification center?

For this you could add a order(or time) variable to your push payload to be able to understand if the user is selecting/activating the app trough a push older that a previous one selected.
Check [**this page**](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/ApplePushService/ApplePushService.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH100-SW1) for more on **adding extra data** to the Push Notification.